# C# Form Application - Stop an ongoing process with a click of another button

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to stop an ongoing process with a button click in Windows form application?

1. For example, let's say there are 2 buttons, "START" and "STOP"
2. When you press "START", it will start an infinite loop, printing numbers from 1 to infinity.
3. When I press "STOP", the process should stop at that moment.
4. But the problem is, I cannot press the "STOP" button as it does not allow me, since there's an ongoing process.

Is there a way to overcome this?

I know there's something called "MethodInvoker", but I have no idea how that works or whether it is relevant to this.

```
    private bool keepRunning = true;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void StartBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var number = 1;
        while (keepRunning)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            MesgeLabel.Text = "" + number++;
        }
    }

    private void StopBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Cannot even click this button
        keepRunning = false;
        //or
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

Comment: It's always helpful to show the code otherwise we'll just be guessing what is going on with your program.

Comment: My code is a bit long, but I'll create a shorter version and upload

Comment: Hi. Are you still there? Did any of the solutions help you?

Comment: Oguz Ozgul - Your solution worked for me mate. There was a slight issue though. It gives me an exception when I try to put text on a label. But this is just a test application, so thanks to you I found a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT 1:

If you need to interact with UI controls, doing it from a background task would throw invalid operation -> illegal cross thread exception. To overcome this,

check `Control.InvokeRequired`

```
if(myLabel.InvokeRequired)
    myLabel.Invoke(new Action(() => myLabel.Text = newText));
else
    myLabel.Text = newText;
```

You can start a `Task` by providing a CancellationToken and cancel the operation when the stop button is clicked.

The task will execute the infinite loop on another thread and your main thread (the UI thread) should not be affected and should be accessible.

Try this:

```
/*
    Please add these on top of your form class

    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
*/

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;
    CancellationToken cancellationToken;

    private void CountToInfinity()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            Debug.WriteLine(new Random().Next());
        }
    }

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cancellationTokenSource == null)
        {
            cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            cancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;
            Task.Run((Action)CountToInfinity, cancellationToken);
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cancellationTokenSource != null)
        {
            cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
            cancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
            cancellationTokenSource = null;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: This worked, and thank you Oguz Ozgul. Ran into a slight issue though, cannot add text to the label, gives an exception - "Cross-thread operation not valid" ... but since this is a test application I do not need that part

Comment: Of course, if you are manipulating UI controls you need the manipulation operation to run on the UI thread. I am adding how to do that to my solution now.

Comment: Perfect dude   Works without a single issue   Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

If you have spawned a new process then you can call kill method.

```cs
Process myProcess = Process.Start("Notepad.exe")//starts new process
myProcess.Kill();// kills the process. save reference to myProcess and call kill on STOP button click
```

If you have started new thread then call abort method to stop the thread.

```cs
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(method)); 
thread.Start(); 
thread.Abort(); // terminates the thread. call abort on STOP button click
```

Comment: I cannot even press the button while the other process is running. So, any workaround for that?

Comment: because your UI thread is occupied with updating MesgeLabel.Text and Thread.Sleep(). Thread.Sleep() does not release UI thread.

Comment: Yes that was kinda the problem I needed the solution for. I know it's no issue, but I was kinda looking to access my UI while the process is going

Answer (score 0):

When you press the "start" button, the code that runs and prints the numbers will run on the ui thread. (from your explanation, i assume that all you have is the message handler for the button press event and nothing else. e.g.: Not setting up a seperate thread.).

Running an infinite loop on the ui thread means, that you do not get any more time for processing other messages. (the thread that is responsible for processing the ui messages is stuck in your infinite loop.)

So, in order to be able to press the "stop" button, you need to run the code with the infinite loop in a different thread or in a different process altogether. This is what Arjun is trying to tell you. (if you want the code in the infinite loop to access resources from your form app, you need a thread. [the thread is inside the forms app process.])

please note: if you create a thread and run your number printing code inside that thread, this will not be the ui thread. Thus, you will not be able to interact with the forms controls as if you'd be on the ui thread. (i.e.: trying to set the windows.text in order to display your numbers will most likely throw an exception.)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation  I will try different options. Currently Oguz Ozgul's solution worked for me